# sudo apt-get update failed to Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com, where able to perform apt-get update root

Tags: apt

Am using ubuntu 20.04, where using proxy to connect internet.

Able to perform "apt-get update" as "root"

where not able to perform "apt-get update" && apt-get install vnc" as non-root user with sudo prefix

Comment: You should provide the exact command as used and error message obtained. It could be you mis-used the `sudo` in the second set of commands you gave (did you use it for both?)

Comment: As root user able to run "apt-get update", where as non-root user not able to run "sudo apt-get update"

Comment: Provide the full command & error message (added to your question).  The message(s) provided should reveal your issue; your wording in the question does not exclude command error.

Comment: Here is result of "sudo apt-get update"                                                                              
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out

Comment: Here is result of "apt-get update" 
Hit:1 http://adc.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:3 http://adc.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:4 http://adc.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Fetched 252 kB in 1s (260 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done